# How to implement collapsible table rows in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'd like to have tables that can dynamically collapse some rows in a web page, such as:

```
    |   Title   |   Foo   |   Bar   |
    ---------------------------------
    | + My First Section            |
    ---------------------------------
    | + My Second Section           |
    ---------------------------------
```

can dynamically expand to

```
    |   Title   |   Foo   |   Bar   |
    ---------------------------------
    | - My First Section            |
    ---------------------------------
    | 1st Title |    42   |  $10.00 |
    ---------------------------------
    | 2nd Title |    74   |  $12.00 |
    ---------------------------------
    | + My Second Section           |
    ---------------------------------
```

when I press on the `+` sign.

Are there any JavaScript libraries that could help me do such a thing, or is there some magic native command that could do it for my easily?

Answer (score 2):

Put each section in a different tbody element, each with an id attribute. Make the first row of each tbody a single header cell (th with the appropriate colspan) with your section header text and an anchor to #the_tbody_id. Then:

1. Add CSS:

   tbody[id]:not(:target) > tr:first-child + tr { display: none !important; }
2. Or, for non-partial-CSS3 browsers, add Javascript to hide the non-first rows in each of those tbodys (eg, loop through tablelement.getElementsByTagName("tbody")), and hook the anchor to toggle their display property on click (eg, loop through tbodyelement.getElementsByTagName("tr")).

Comment: Setting display on table rows is tricky. What do you set the display property to when you want to display the tr? block? Heh. A TR is not a block level element.

Comment: No, you would set it to 'table-row' if you were setting it. But you obviously don't have to. Toggle the .style.display property between the values 'none' and ''.

Comment: @Anonymous, it would be great if you could post a code sample.

Answer (score 0):

You just write a div with display none inside every TR. And on the '+' sign click change the display of the div to block and on '-' click change it again to none.

Assign each div a unique id.

Eg:

```
<tr>
    <td>
       My Section>
       <div style='display:none'>
          Content goes here
       </div>
   </td>        
</tr>
```

Comment: Quick test shows that solution almost working.  There's no need for a <div> section, though. When the "style" argument is applied to the <tr> tag, I can actually show / hide entire rows.  The test was done statically, though. I still have to hook it to some javascript action.

Answer (score 0):

Dojo and Jquery both can do this for you, but in case you don't want to use a javascript library this isn't hard with just plain JavaScript. Use an onclick event handler for the +/- toggle, write a function that is executed which sets a block element (one of your sets of rows) to display:none (a css rule). If you're going to use a table to display this, don't try to dynamically hide or show table rows, it doesn't work well.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the display property of those rows as none, and reset it as "table-row" at click.

But I think that IE doesn't render this appropiately though...

Answer (score 0):

I found the other answers helpful but I didn't see a good explanation with an example so here is how I did it with a simple HTML file...

For the rows you want to show/hide, wrap them in a `tbody` element and give it a unique `id`:

```
<tbody id="collapsible-rows" style="display: none;">
    <tr>
        <td>Col1 data 3</td>
        <td>Col2 data 3</td>
        <td>Col3 data 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Col1 data 4</td>
        <td>Col2 data 4</td>
        <td>Col3 data 4</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Here I have set `display: none` so the rows will be hidden initially/by default.
On the header for the collapsible section add an `onclick` method:

```
<tr onclick="CollapseRows()">
    <th colspan="3" id="click-to-expand">Not So Important Information (click to expand)</th>
</tr>
```

I have used "(click to expand)" and "(click to collapse)" as the changing text but you could just as easily use "+" and "-".

Below is the method, which does two things. 1) Gets a reference to the `tbody` element and collapses or expands the rows by setting `display` to `none` or to `table-row-group`. 2) Gets a reference to the section header and changes the displayed text when it's clicked.

```
function CollapseRows(){
    let collapsibleRows = document.getElementById("collapsible-rows");
    let clickToExpand = document.getElementById("click-to-expand");

    if (collapsibleRows.style.display === "none") {
        collapsibleRows.style.display = "table-row-group";
        clickToExpand.innerHTML = "Not So Important Information (click to collapse)";
    } else {
        collapsibleRows.style.display = "none";
        clickToExpand.innerHTML = "Not So Important Information (click to expand)";
    }
}
```

[image: collapsible rows gif]

Here is the full example:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        table {
            width: 400px;
        }

        table, td {
            border: 1px solid #333; /*border size & color*/
            border-collapse: collapse; /*No margin around the cells*/
        }

        th /*table header*/
        {
            background-color: #e8f6fc; /*Header row color*/
            color: #000000; /*header row text color*/
            border: 1px solid #333;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        function CollapseRows(){
            let collapsibleRows = document.getElementById("collapsible-rows");
            let clickToExpand = document.getElementById("click-to-expand");

            if (collapsibleRows.style.display === "none") {
                collapsibleRows.style.display = "table-row-group";
                clickToExpand.innerHTML = "Not So Important Information (click to collapse)";
            } else {
                collapsibleRows.style.display = "none";
                clickToExpand.innerHTML = "Not So Important Information (click to expand)";
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Column 1</th>
        <th>Column 2</th>
        <th>Column 3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="3">Important Information</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Col1 data 1</td>
        <td>Col2 data 1</td>
        <td>Col3 data 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Col1 data 2</td>
        <td>Col2 data 2</td>
        <td>Col3 data 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr onclick="CollapseRows()">
        <th colspan="3" id="click-to-expand">Not So Important Information (click to expand)</th>
    </tr>
    <tbody id="collapsible-rows" style="display: none;">
        <tr>
            <td>Col1 data 3</td>
            <td>Col2 data 3</td>
            <td>Col3 data 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Col1 data 4</td>
            <td>Col2 data 4</td>
            <td>Col3 data 4</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</html>
```