# How to Split Table nicely in JSP

Tags: javascript, html, spring, jsp, struts

I have created a table for displaying books be signed out/in of an department.  There are sorted on:  Name, Date.  Every so often (after some check-ins and check outs are made) the books are inventoried to confirm how many are available (and numbers are corrected according).

I currently have a table that displays all of the books sorted by Name, Date.  But since there are a lot of rows I was hoping to have collapsible section based on when this type of book was inventoried.

Desired:

```
Name |  Date | Count | Action
-----------------------------
- First Foo Section -
Foo    SomeD     +3    check-in
Foo    SomeD     -1    check-out
Foo    SomeD     5     inventoried
+ Another Foo Section
+ Bar Section
```

Current Code:

```
<c:forEach var='item' items='${bookLogs}'>
            <tr>
                <td>${f:replaceNewLineWithBR(f:escapeHtml(item.name))}</td>
                <td><c:out value='${item.date.formattedValue}'/></td>
                <td>${f:replaceNewLineWithBR(f:escapeHtml(item.count))}</td>
                <td>${f:replaceNewLineWithBR(f:escapeHtml(item.actionType))}</td>
            </tr>
    </c:forEach>
```

Should I do a test on item.actionType?  Or should I pass bookLogs as a list of lists for the different collapsing sections in the table?

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/801082/how-to-implement-collapsible-table-rows-in-javascript][1]

You have a duplicate question just letting you know.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/801082/how-to-implement-collapsible-table-rows-in-javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My comment above didn't answer your question but here is a tutorial on how to do it http://www.a2ztechguide.com/2011/07/javascript-expand-collapse-table-rows.html.

I did this a long time ago with a database and it is no fun now we are using xml and display just what we need.

The link above does a great job and explains how to use javascript to make the expand and collapse. Your above code was on the right track but not quite there yet.

Comment: Well this is a step in the right direction, but I need the sections to be dynamically generated and I won't know how many sections will be needed per bookLogs

Comment: Have your server define each one so that it has a value of the section so like `<td value="sectionname">Row1</td>` and the server would change `sectionname` to what the section name is so then your javascript would find all sectionnames then link them as a group and then you can hide the group

Comment: Well overall it doesn't say everything I need.  I've gotten to the point now that the table is all in sections, but I don't know how best to create and store the id's of the elements of each section.

Comment: Well do the id need to be shown or just a thing in the code that will end up linking to a page like book?id=87 because you could set `<td value="sectionname" id="idnumber"> Row 1 </td>`

Comment: Well I have a book ID and a transaction ID, the book ID cannot be used since there can be multiple sections that use that book.  So it would have to transaction ID, but how does that get grouped with the rest of them for their section?

Comment: I assume that you have a data that is called or like section name for each book right?

Comment: Well I was able to solve the issue on my own by giving each 'Expand Row" an iterating sectionID (id='sectionID'), and for it's children rows to have id='sectionId-RowId' to unique identify all of them.

Comment: Are you going to award the bounty?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you use widely available JS based Table/Grid solutions for clients.

http://www.omnisdata.com/omnigrid/

http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxGrid/index.shtml

and many others.I have personally used Omnigrid and found its worth investing a couple of hours to come up with this kind of a thing which scales to future requirements and current trends.

Answer (score 0):

Look into Bootstrap, it has some really epic features, especially with tables.

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/